# Mongoose.connect not throwing any error, when Mongodb is not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Solved: if anybody is interested, it seems that MongoDB is just starting automatically on Windows startup...

I have this function to initialize a Mongoose connection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let db;

async function initDD(){
    try {
       db  = await  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/local', { useNewUrlParser: true });   

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('mongoose error',error)//Doesn't come to this...
    }

}
```

This promise doesn't get rejected, even if i haven't started my MongoDB service yet. I tried also the callback version- same result. I clearly do not have any MongoDB running, and yet Mongoose "connects" as if nothing is wrong.

What could be the problem here? I have a standard MongoDB setup, latest Mongoose, Windows 7 and Node 10.

Edit: the logged value of the "db", when no MogoDB is running:

```
Mongoose {
  connections:
   [ NativeConnection {
       base: [Circular],
       collections: [Object],
       models: [Object],
       config: [Object],
       replica: false,
       options: null,
       otherDbs: [],
       relatedDbs: {},
       states: [Object],
       _readyState: 1,
       _closeCalled: false,
       _hasOpened: true,
       plugins: [],
       _listening: false,
       _connectionOptions: [Object],
       name: 'local',
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 27017,
       user: undefined,
       pass: undefined,
       client: [MongoClient],
       '$initialConnection': [Promise],
       db: [Db] } ],
  models: { User: Model { User } },
  modelSchemas:
   { User:
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        methodOptions: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Array],
        '$id': 1,
        s: [Object],
        _userProvidedOptions: {},
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true } },
  options: { pluralization: true, [Symbol(mongoose:default)]: true },
  _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
  Schema:
   { [Function: Schema]
     reserved:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        populated: 1,
        remove: 1,
        validate: 1,
        toObject: 1,
        schema: 1,
        save: 1,
        modelName: 1,
        get: 1,
        isNew: 1,
        isModified: 1,
        init: 1,
        errors: 1,
        db: 1,
        collection: 1,
        removeListener: 1,
        listeners: 1,
        once: 1,
        on: 1,
        emit: 1,
        prototype: 1 },
     Types:
      { String: [Function],
        Number: [Function],
        Boolean: [Function],
        DocumentArray: [Function],
        Embedded: [Function: SingleNestedPath],
        Array: [Function],
        Buffer: [Function],
        Date: [Function],
        ObjectId: [Function],
        Mixed: [Function],
        Decimal: [Function],
        Decimal128: [Function],
        Map: [Function: Map],
        Oid: [Function],
        Object: [Function],
        Bool: [Function],
        ObjectID: [Function] },
     ObjectId:
      { [Function: ObjectId]
        schemaName: 'ObjectId',
        get: [Function],
        _checkRequired: [Function],
        _cast: [Function: castObjectId],
        cast: [Function: cast],
        checkRequired: [Function] } },
  model: [Function],
  plugins:
   [ [ [Function], [Object] ],
     [ [Function], [Object] ],
     [ [Function], [Object] ],
     [ [Function], [Object] ] ] }
```

Comment: can you log the value of the db variable?

Comment: check my edited post

Comment: do you able to connect MongoDB on your terminal/cmd.

Comment: I now see in my Windows "services" tab that thre is a mongoDB running. Is it possible MongoDB just auto connects?

Comment: Please stop that service, and check it again.

Comment: where and how do you call initDD?

Comment: I call initDb from my main index.js file in node. So it seems that MongoDB is indeed starting automatically on Windows startup. I restarted my pc, and this service was there. Also, i'm able to fetch data from the db using my api, without manually starting mongoDB. Have no clue what or who is starting my mongo :D

Comment: This is totally normal, it's not `mongo` that is starting for your app. It's `mongod` listening for commands!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Windows too. Once Mongo is installed it runs in the background and it's fine, otherwise you'd have to start manually a `mongod` instance each time.

I prefer to use `then/catch` even if `try/catch` is now supported:

```
mongoose.connect(
        'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',{
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        }
    )
    .then(() => console.log('DB Connection Successfull'))
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

If you don't want to buffer your models, thus getting confusing behaviour, you need to disable it either on your schema or globally:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#bufferCommands
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering

reference: `mongoose` docs

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure. but I think you should execute the function.
await initDD ().
It is little code to understand what happens.

something like that

//database.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
  async function connect() {
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_SERVER, {
   useNewUrlParser: true
  });
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 1) {
   console.log("Successfully connected to database");
  }
 }
module.exports = { connect };
```

// index.js

```
const app = require("./app");
const { connect } = require("./database");
async function main() {
 // dayabase conexion
 await connect();
 // start server
 const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
 await app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server on port ${port} `));
}
main();
```

replace process.env.DATABASE_SERVER, with 'mongodb://localhost:27017/local'

Comment: I think the "problem" was just mongodb running on windows startup, without me realizing it :D

Answer (score 1):

Try MongoClient.connect

```
async function initDD() {
  try {
    await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error is ->" + error);
  }
}
initDD();
```

Error is -

```
error is ->MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```